# No such file or directory in copying file to hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

i'm beginner in hadoop, when i use

```
Hadoop fs -ls /
```

And

```
Hadoop fs - mkdir /pathname
```

Every thing is ok, but i want to use my csv file in hadoop, my file is in c drive, i used `-put` and `wget` and `copyfromlocal` commands like these:

```
Hadoop fs -put c:/ path / myhadoopdir
Hadoop fs copyFromLoacl c:/...
Wget ftp://c:/...
```

But in two of above it errors in no such file or directory /myfilepathinc:
And for the third
Unable to resolve host address"c"
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

salmanbw's answer is exact. To be more clear.

Suppose your file is "c:\testfile.txt", use the command below.
And also make sure you have write permission to your directory in HDFS.

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal c:\testfile.txt /HDFSdir/testfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your command, it seems that there could be couple of reasons for this issue.

```
 Hadoop fs -put c:/ path / myhadoopdir
 Hadoop fs copyFromLoacl c:/...
```

1. Use hadoop fs -copyFromLocal correctly.
2. Check your local file permission. You have to give full access to that file.
3. You have to give your absolute path location both in local and in hdfs.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thank you, but how can i check my local file permission or full access?!

Comment: You can do ls -lrt to see the permission of your file   -rwxrwxrwx 1 user user       0 May 13 05:01 salmanbw.txt .  refer to this link http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/help/chmod.html to see if you have full access to path or not.